# A vbs script to remove annotation

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have a basic vbs code to split a file name at the first underscore. Eg:t_e_s_t becomes t.
I dont want to split the file name, I want to remove the annotation of the file name
that would consist out of "." "_" and spaces.

Please can someone just have a look at the code and tell me how to modify it?

```
Option Explicit

Dim strPath
Dim FSO
Dim FLD
Dim fil
Dim strOldName
Dim strNewName
Dim strFileParts

    'Define the path to the file
    strPath = inputbox("File path:")

    'Create the instance of the FSO
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Set the folder you want to search. NOTE - some antivirus may not like this
    Set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(strPath)

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    For Each fil in FLD.Files
        'Get complete file name with path
        strOldName = fil.Path

        'Check the file has an underscore in the name
        If InStr(strOldName, "_") > 0 Then

'Split the file on the underscore so we can get everything before it
 strFileParts = Split(strOldName, "_")

'Build the new file name with everything before the 

'first under score plus the extension
 strNewName = strFileParts(0) & ".txt"

'Use the MoveFile method to rename the file
 FSO.MoveFile strOldName, strNewName

    End If
    Next

    'Cleanup the objects
    Set FLD = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
strNewName = Replace(strOldName, "_", "") & ".txt"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it, and with some ajustment this will do exactly what I want it to!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of publishing code that does not do what you want, you should specify exactly what input should be transformed to what output. E.g: "t e.s_t" should become "test". Then it would be easy to come up with some proof of concept code:

```
>> Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function
>> Function clean(s)
>>   clean = Replace(Replace(Replace(s, " ", ""), ".", ""), "_", "")
>> End Function
>> a = Array("test", "t e s t", "t_e.s t")
>> For i = 1 To UBound(a)
>>     c = clean(a(i))
>>     WScript.Echo qq(a(i)), qq(c), CStr(c = a(0))
>> Next
>>
"t e s t" "test" True
"t_e.s t" "test" True
>>
```

and really interesting questions like:

1. Why apply the modification to the full path (strOldName = fil.Path)?
2. What should happen to the dot before the extension?

Comment: Sorry man!! i did say this is my first time!! and i am not a now it all about code thats wy i asked for help!! is that to much?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "[._ ]"
re.Global  = True

For Each fil in FLD.Files
  basename  = FLD.GetBaseName(fil)
  extension = FLD.GetExtensionName(fil)
  fil.Name = re.Replace(basename, "") & "." & extension
Next
```

If you want to mangle the extension and append a new extension `.txt` to each file regardless of type use this loop instead:

```
For Each fil in FLD.Files
  fil.Name = re.Replace(fil.Name, "") & ".txt"
Next
```